# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 app does not save authentication cookies on device(JSESSIONID, WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE)

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a MobileFirst 6.3 app and I've implemented a custom Authenticator (from the getting started samples) and LoginModule. When running the app in the Mobile Browser Simulator, the device runtime stores the cookies (I am able to see them in Chrome developer tools) but when running the app on a device (Huawei P6 - Android 4.4.2) the cookies are not saved (after a successful login).

There are no errors in Eclipse LogCat or Console.

What can make the device runtime save the cookies when running the app on device?

Answer (score 0):

please check if your Android is configured to accept cookies. 
Settings > Applications > Internet > Content Settings > Accept Cookies

Regards,

Comment: I could not find the path you mentioned in the device settings. I checked that the cookies are accepted in all installed browsers (pre-installed one and Chrome). I've also checked on Android emulator which behaves the same as the device: cookies not saved.